MANOVA with some dependent variables being ordinal and some being interval
A MANOVA test seems to be a good fit for the following study except that the dependent variables are not interval as required, I want to examine how heritage and non-heritage learners differ on two genres of writing as reflected in 1) Overall impression, 2) Content, 3) Organization, 4) Vocab accuracy, and 5) Grammar accuracy. Learners (heritage and non-heritage) and genres (narrative and argumentative) are two independent variables. Overall, content, and organization are rated on a scale of 1 through 5 and therefore these three dependent variables are ordinal while vocab and grammar are calculated on percentage and therefore these two dependent variables are interval.
My questions are 1) Can I still use MANOVA? 2) If not, what other test can I use? and 3) If yes, what modification can I use to make MANOVA work?
I have limited knowledge of statistics and use SPSS most of the times, but am willing to try other software if they can handle this problem more effectively. Thank you very much!!

I am sorry for being confusing. I have just modified the title. Actually, I meant to ask if I can use MANOVA if some dependent variables are ordinal while some are interval. The details of the study design was explained.
Thanks for your reply. Hope that your laptop will be back to normal soon!

MANOVA does not require that independent variables be interval. In fact, like all the ANOVAs, it's sort of designed for categorical IVs, although ANOVA is mathematically equivalent to regression.
It does require that the dependent variable be interval.
I am not sure that you really need a multivariate approach. If you look at each DV separately, you could use ordinal logistic regression for the ordinal DV.
If you do need a multivariate approach,  then some form of multivariate regression would be right; these models are pretty complex.
(I would write more but my laptop is being repaired and it's hard to write math on my phone)
